# Сортировка 2-го списка по первому

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, сортировка

Есть две переменные **`a`** и **`b`** и в них текст:

```
a = '''
 SadneSStrait (123456789)  —  3,991  |
 moon (123456789)  —  2,719  |
 kel (123456789)  —  1,755  |
 nick (123456789)  —  933    |  
 yet (123456789)  —  263    |  
 Gerd (123456789)  —  262  |
 Ion (123456789)  —  142  |

'''
```

---

```
b = '''
 Ion (123456789)  —  3,000   | 
 SadneSStrait  (123456789)  —  2,868  |
 Gerd (123456789)  —  2,000  |
 kel (123456789)  —  1,967  |
 moon (123456789)  —  1,912    |  
 yet (123456789)  —  1,321  |
 nick (123456789)  —  1,123  |

'''
```

Строки я разделил.
Нужно отсортировать текст в **`b`** таким образом, чтобы было, как в переменной **`a`**

Comment: Порядковый номер в начале следует учитывать, или это для наглядности?

Comment: для наглядности

Comment: как в переменной `a` - это по номеру, который идет после слова "Игрок"?

Comment: @strawdog Я думаю по статусу (эмодзи)

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: переправил имена

Comment: условие не понятно. как в переменной a по-вашему отсортированы строки?

Comment: Текст в переменной "а" это текст полученный методом копирования из другого источника

Comment: @Aman По какому принципу он отсортирован? По имени, по айди, по очкам? От чего отталкиваться то? Задача не ясна.

Comment: По очкам, если есть вариант, то я бы хотел сразу узнать (не только получить ответ), как можно сразу высчитывать, на сколько очков прибавилось у определённого игрока с прошлой проверки (отнять кол-во очков у игрока из переменной  "б" и "а")

Answer (score 2):

Пока не ясно, как конкретно автор вопроса хотел отсортировать строку, можно показать универсальный пример с сортировкой по номеру, идущему после слова "Игрок", в котором останется поменять ключ на нужный:

```
b_lst=[y for y in [x.split() for x in b.split("\n")] if len(y)]
res = sorted(b_lst, key=lambda x: x[3])
b = "\n".join(" ".join(x) for x in res)
print(b)
```

```
3.  Игрок 1 (123456789) — 1,867  |
7.  Игрок 2 (123456789) — 1,123  |
2.  Игрок 3 (123456789) — 2,868  |
6.  Игрок 4 (123456789) — 1,321  |
4.  Игрок 5 (123456789) — 1000  |
5.  Игрок 6 (123456789) — 312  |
1.  Игрок 7 (123456789) — 2,000  |
```

Comment: Не подходит, я переправил условие

Answer (score 1):

```
weight_map = { 
    "" : 8,
    "" : 4,
    "" : 2 
}

list_2d = [line.split() for line in b.split("\n") if line]
list_2d.sort(key=lambda lst: (weight_map[lst[1]], int(lst[6].replace(",", ""))), reverse=True)
lines = "\n".join(" ".join(line) for line in list_2d)
print(lines)
```

**Output:**

```
1.  Игрок 7 (123456789) — 2,000  |
2.  Игрок 3 (123456789) — 2,868  |
3.  Игрок 1 (123456789) — 1,867  |
4.  Игрок 5 (123456789) — 1000  |
5.  Игрок 6 (123456789) — 312  |
6.  Игрок 4 (123456789) — 1,321  |
7.  Игрок 2 (123456789) — 1,123  |
```

Comment: Не подходит, я переправил условие

Answer (score 0):

Получилось примерно так:

```
b = '''
 Игрок 5 (123456789)  —  1000   | 
 Игрок 3 (123456789)  —  2,868  |
 Игрок 7 (123456789)  —  2,000  |
 Игрок 1 (123456789)  —  1,867  |
 Игрок 6 (123456789)  —  312    |  
 Игрок 4 (123456789)  —  1,321  |
 Игрок 2 (123456789)  —  1,123  |
'''

def sorting_key(line):
    if line.startswith(''):
        return 0
    elif line.startswith(''):
        return 1
    elif line.startswith(''):
        return 2
    else:
        return 3

sorted_b = sorted(b.splitlines(), key=sorting_key)

for line in sorted_b:
    print(line)
```

**Вывод:**

```
 Игрок 7 (123456789)  —  2,000  |
 Игрок 5 (123456789)  —  1000   |
 Игрок 3 (123456789)  —  2,868  |
 Игрок 1 (123456789)  —  1,867  |
 Игрок 6 (123456789)  —  312    |
 Игрок 4 (123456789)  —  1,321  |
 Игрок 2 (123456789)  —  1,123  |
```

Comment: Не подходит, я переправил условие